# Is this dynamic programming or divide and conquer?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I'm in the middle of studying algorithms. There is an article I read indirectly discussing the knapsack problem. In the end it is said to be solved with dynamic programming but to me it looks like just divide and conquer with minor optimizations. Can someone have a look? 
I have pasted the code into a bin http://jsbin.com/sulipipole/edit?js,console.

```
const ACTIVITIES = [
  {name: 'side-project', time: 10, xp: 12},
  {name: 'algorithms', time: 3, xp: 7},
  {name: 'networking', time: 1, xp: 0.5},
  {name: 'exercise', time: 2, xp: 1.5},
  {name: 'systems design', time: 4, xp: 4},
  {name: 'making CSS codepens', time: 3, xp: 4}
];


const findJob = function(time, activities) {

    const optimalSolution = function(items, n = items.length, timeLeft = time) {

    if (n === 0 || timeLeft === 0) {
      return [];
    }

    if (items[n - 1].time > timeLeft) {
      return optimalSolution(items, n - 1, timeLeft);
    }

     const lastItem = items[n - 1];

    const withLastItem = [
      lastItem,
      ...optimalSolution(items, n - 1, timeLeft - lastItem.time)
    ];
    const withoutLastItem = optimalSolution(items, n - 1, timeLeft);

    if (totalXp(withLastItem) > totalXp(withoutLastItem)) {
      return withLastItem;
    } else {
      return withoutLastItem;
    }
    };

    const totalXp = arr => arr.reduce((total, ea) => total + ea.xp, 0);

    const sortedByTime = activities
      .slice()
      .sort((a, b) => a.time - b.time);

    return optimalSolution(sortedByTime)
      .map(act => act.name);
    };
```

Dynamic programming requires some memoization or tabling scheme correct?

Comment: I'd say this is neither dynamic programming nor divide'n'conquer. It's just a recursive algorithm to generate the [power set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) and find the subset of jobs that consumes less time than available with the maximum xp.

Comment: Thanks for the response. After thinking about it a bit, I can understand why it's not divide'n'conquer either. Also, given the xp calculation, this is a O(n * 2^n) time algorithm, correct? And not a O(n * nT) algorithm, T being time.

Comment: The problem _should_ be solved with dynamic programming, but the code you provide doesn't do that.  The code you pasted in just tests all of the possibilities to find the best one.  This kind of approach is called "brute force" or "exhaustive search".

Answer (score 1):

I really like the way Skiena described dynamic programming in his book "the algorithm design manual". "Dynamic programming is a technique for efficiently implementing a recursive algorithm by storing partial results".

You have a recursive algorithm here but no storing of partial results. So it is not dynamic programming. But it can probably be turned into a dynamic programming algorithm by storing and reusing the partial results.